# Can there be an injective function whose derivative is equivalent to its inverse function?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, functional-equations, inverse-function

Let's say $f:D\to R$ is an injective function on some domain where it is also differentiable. For a real function, i.e. $D\subset\mathbb R, R\subset\mathbb R$, is it possible that $f'(x)\equiv f^{-1}(x)$?

Intuitively speaking, <s>I suspect that this is not possible</s>, but I can't provide a reasonable proof since I know <s>very little</s> *nothing* about functional analysis. Can anyone provide a (counter)example or prove that such function does not exist?

Comment: Can you be clearer about the domains?  Is $f$ supposed to be a bijection $D\to R$?  If so, then shouldn't $D=R$, since $D$ is the domain of $f'$ and $R$ is the domain of $f^{-1}$?  And is $D$ required to be an interval?

Comment: @EricWofsey Yes it should. I stated the problem in general form. But this assumption restricts $R$ to be equal to $D$

Comment: "[Functional analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_analysis)" has a specific meaning which is different from what you had in mind, I don't think it has any relevance to questions like this.

Comment: If you pick $g$ so that $f(g(x)) = g(x+1)$, then the problem reduces to solving the delay differential equation $g(x-1) g'(x) = g'(x+1)$. Unfortunately I have no good ideas for that one.

Comment: @Hurkyl Does the Greg's answer fit into your equation? I wasn't able to verify that

Comment: @polfosol: Unpleasantly. By looking at the formula for iterates of $f$, $g(x) = C^{(n^x - 1)/(n-1)} a^{n^{x-1}}$ should do the trick for $f(x) = C x^n$. ($a$ can be anything, although this will treat the regions above and below the fixed point separately)

Answer (score 83, accepted):

It is possible! Here is an example on the domain $D=[0,\infty)$:
$$
f(x) = \bigg(\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2}\bigg)^{(\sqrt5-1)/2} x^{(\sqrt5+1)/2}.
$$
I found this by supposing that $f(x)$ had the form $ax^b$, setting the derivative equal to the inverse function, and solving for $a$ and $b$.

[image: graph of $f(x)$ and $f'(x)$]

Comment: Robert Israel beat me by two minutes :)

Comment: Nice answer. Now what about the case where $D=\mathbb R$?

Comment: @polfosol: That is impossible, since in order to be injective $f$ must be monotone, so $f'$ must always have the same sign.

Comment: Thanks @EricWofsey and Greg

Comment: Is it a coincidence that $f(x)=(\phi-1)^{\phi-1}x^{\phi}$, where $\phi$ is the golden ratio? Probably, but still noteworthy :)

Comment: @Lovsovs Or $f(x)=\frac{x^\phi}{\sqrt[\phi]{\phi}}$

Comment: @Lovsovs: Of course it's **not** a coindicence. $\phi^2=\phi+1$ or equivalently $\phi^{-1}=\phi-1$. For a function $ax^b$, the derivative has exponent $b-1$ and the inverse has exponent $b^{-1}$, so for them to be equal $b$ must be a solution of $b^{-1}=b-1$, either the normal golden ratio or the other solution. And since the exponent is the golden ratio, and the coefficient is chosen so everything fits, it's natural that it will be based on $\phi$ as well.

Comment: Don't use JPG for diagrams!

Comment: What's the reason for no JPG? What's the preferred file format?

Comment: @GregMartin: Probably PNG is better. That way the background of the image will (often) be transparent and the image as a whole will blend into the webpage better. As it is, I can tell by looking that, if you have used a PNG image, the background has not been made transparent: the website is an off-white colour, while the image is pure white. It doesn't look *bad* (in this case), but it is noticeable.

Comment: I'm having trouble figuring out if this is unique on D, or if other solutions exist. Anyone have any insight on this?

Answer (score 41):

On $(0, \infty)$, take $f(x) = a x^p$ where $p = (\sqrt{5}+1)/2$ (so that $p(p-1) = 1$) and
$a = p^{-1/p}$.

Answer (score 24):

There have already been examples with $f: D \to \mathbb R$, but note that it is not possible with $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$. A simple argument is that for a function $f$ to be injective, necessarily $f'(x) \geq 0$ or $f'(x) \leq 0$ for all $x$. Thus we can see that for there to be equality between $f'(x)$ and $f^{-1}(x)$, then we must have $f^{-1}(x) \geq 0$ or $f^{-1}(x) \leq 0$ for all $x$.

But this can't happen, because any function defined on $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ must have its inverse go from positive to negative for some $x$. To confirm this, just look at the fact that the inverse of any horizontal line must cross the x-axis by flipping over the line $y=x$, and then add curves to that line to find that nothing has changed, and it still must cross the x-axis.

Comment: A right arrow symbol for 'tends to' or 'goes to' is not 'dash + greater-than' but rather a LaTeX symbol `\to` (usually synonym to `\rightarrow`), which renders as $\to$.

Comment: @CiaPan I think `\mapsto` is more appropriate

Comment: I changed it to \to, thanks for the tip.

Comment: @polfosol No, `\mapsto` is used for denoting a single value mapping. For example, $f: C\to X$ expresses we mean a function $f$ going from a set $C$ to a set $X$, while $q: x\mapsto \sin (x/2)$ expresses we mean a function $q$ which assigns each $x$ argument a value of a sine of a half of $x$. See Wikipedia article ['List of mathematical symbols', section 'Symbols that point left or right'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_symbols#Symbols_that_point_left_or_right)

Comment: @CiaPan [You are right](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_(mathematics)#Notation)

Comment: The example given is for $f: R \to R$, so this argument must be flawed. Did you mean $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ instead?

Comment: @PeterTaylor Yes, sorry about that. I've changed the respective "R"'s to the symbol for the real numbers instead. Thank you.

Comment: An easier way to observe that we can't have $f^{-1}$ always positive or always negative is that it's positive at $f(1)$ and negative at $f(-1)$...

Comment: @BenMillwood Also true. Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

Since someone mentioned whether the answer given by Robert Israel / Greg Martin might be unique, I thought it is worth noting that the function
$$f(x)=-\frac{1}{\phi^\phi}(-x)^{-\frac{1}{\phi}},\quad x<0$$
where $\phi$ is the golden ratio, has the same property on $D=(-\infty,0)$, i.e. $f'(x)\equiv f^{-1}(x)$.

**Edit-** So if we define:
$$f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R\\x\mapsto a(x/a)^a$$
where $a=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}\text{ sign}(x)}{2}$, we would have a bijection on $\mathbb R$ with that nice property (yay!...).

[image]

Comment: And, I know that $f'(x)\ne f^{-1}(x)$, _**but**:_ $f'(x)\equiv f^{-1}(x)$  :)

Comment: I never imagined the golden ratio would come up in such a strange place!