# When is the inverse function of the derivative equal to the integral?

Tags: derivatives, indefinite-integrals, inverse-function

**Note on duplicates**
[This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1909386/can-there-be-an-injective-function-whose-derivative-is-equivalent-to-its-inverse) question is **not** a duplicate; it asks when the inverse of the derivative equals the **function**, mine asks when the inverse of the derivative equals the **integral**.

**The question**
Let $f$ be any function. Define $F(x)$ to be the integral of $f(x)$, and $(f')^{-1}$ to be the inverse function of the derivative of $f$. When is
$$F(x)=(f')^{-1}?$$
I don't know much about how to solve this equation. Any help would be appreciated.

- $(f')^{-1}$ is not the reciprocal of $f'$.
- I could do this, but I don't know where to begin from. Any hint of where to start from would also be helpful.

**My thoughts and work**

- Does such a function even exist? Why/why not?
- From the initial equation, we get
  $$F^{-1}(x)=f'(x)$$
  Now we use [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_of_inverse_functions?wprov=sfla1) formula, to get
  $$f=xF^{-1}(x)-G\circ F^{-1}(x)+C$$
  Where $G$ is the integral of $F$. So, we get
  $$f=xf'(x)-G\circ f'(x)+C$$
  Now what can be done?

**Motivation**
I have seen many functional/differential equations that are just simple combinations of integrals, derivatives, like [this](https://youtu.be/rNUfiQgj6ZI) which interested me in solving differential equations, that look simple but have hard solutions. This is not from any website/book/article, just my thought.

Comment: Not any function is integrable. Furthermore, the inverse operator of $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}$ does not exist as this operator is not injective (it kernel is $\mathbb{R}$ or  $\mathbb{C}$ depending on the underlying field).

Comment: @Nicolas so it does not exist?

Comment: The fundamental theorem of calculus tells you that if, say, $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]\subset\mathbb{R}$ and $f'$ exists on $[a,b]\setminus Z$ where $Z$ is countable, then the anti-derivative of the derivative gives you back the function $f$ MODULO constants (modulo $\mathbb{R}$ here).

Comment: Well, if $(f')^{-1}=F(x)$ then $F^{-1}(x)=f'(x)$

Comment: Try $f(x):=cx^\alpha$ for $x>0$, and see whether you can fulfill your conditions with suitable choices of $c$ and $\alpha$.

Comment: @GregMartin: read carefully. The question you suggested asks when is the inverse of the derivative equals the **function**, I am asking when the inverse of the derivative equals the **integral**.

Comment: Make an Ansatz $F(x)=ax^b$, find $f’=F’’$ and use $F(f’(x))=x$ to solve for $a$ and $b$

Comment: This question is not a duplicate of the quoted question.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter yes, I mentioned it at the beginning of the question, but they still closed it.

Comment: The derivative of $F(x)$ is $f(x)$; the derivative of $(f')^{-1}(x)$, by the Inverse function Theorem, is $1/(f''(f'(x))$. So taking derivatives of your original equation, you get $f(x)f''(f'(x)) = 1$, don't  you?